# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException [AUTH] Web login required: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu, port, jakarta-mail, ovh

Error Reading Email  with OVH Server ( ubuntu)
I'm working with Springboot in the localhost i can receive the email with my code and I can replay but when I deploy the application with docker image and I run it inside Dedicate server OVH i have this problem,
[image]

I don't know how I can fix this bug ,

When I test the same image docker on another OVH VPS Server is run correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first Sign in - Google Accounts https://accounts.google.com

You need to go here and follow the instructions: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
[image]